# One Parse Android App Receiving Another's Notifications By Mistake

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

We have 2 apps.  They each use Parse, and are each on a different account.  However, when app 1 sends a notification, app 1 AND app 2 receive it.  This is only an issue on Android, not iOS.  We have confirmed that each app uses a unique Application ID, but for the life of us, cannot figure out why the 2nd app is getting notifications for the 1st ones.

The apps are Fritch Church of Christ, and Newalla Church of Christ.  They are for iOS AND Android.  Either app can trigger the following CloudCode:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("newNews", function(request, response) {

    var theTitle = request.params.articleTitle;


  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);


    Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
      alert: "A new article, \"" + theTitle + "\" was just posted.  Open app to view.",



      category : "TAGGED_CATEGORY",

 sound: "default.caf"
    }
  }).then(function() {
      response.success("Push was sent successfully.")
  }, function(error) {
      response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
  });

});
```

Once again, these are separate apps, even on separate accounts, each with their own CloudCode, that just so happens to be identical as we copied and pasted it.

When I send a push using the Fritch app, it sends a push to the Fritch iOS app, the Fritch Android app, and for some weird reason, the Newalla Android app.

When I send a push using the Newalla app, it sends a push to the Newalla iOS app, and the Newalla Android app, but leaves Fritch alone, as would be expected.

Comment: How are the notifications being sent?

Comment: @cricket_007 cloudCode

Comment: And your push query is looking at the same installation  id for the device, I assume?

Comment: Right `Parse.Cloud.define("newNews", function(request, response) {
    var theTitle = request.params.articleTitle;
 
  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
   
    Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
      alert: "A new article, \"" + theTitle + "\" was just posted.  Open app to view.",
       
       
       
      category : "TAGGED_CATEGORY",
      
 sound: "default.caf"
    }
  }).then(function() {
      response.success("Push was sent successfully.")
  }, function(error) {
      response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
  });

});`

Comment: Please update your question with that information. The comments aren't for large code blocks

Comment: Edited the OP to include the code

Comment: So you aren't doing a where filter on the notifications, you just send to all installations?

Comment: Yes, all installations who have that app installed.

Comment: Well, I think that is your problem because I believe the cloud code is per account, not per app. Sending a notification to all installations will do all Parse apps on your account unless you do a filter. I could be wrong, though. It is odd that the iOS devices don't demonstrate the same behavior, so maybe it's just the GCM server on Parse being messed up

Comment: These are on different accounts.  Plus, it only happens when sending from Fritch's cloudCode.  Sending from Newalla's cloudCode doesn't send the notification to Fritch's app.

Comment: Gotcha. And you're sure you deployed the cloud code with the correct account, REST,  and app ids?